# how to prevent "vlcj video output" window

Tags: java, video, applet, vlc, vlcj

I am developing an applet to view camera. But when I run applet a 'vlcj video output' window pops up. Is it possible to remove this window? I tried many times but I could not succeed.

[image]

Comment: VLC opens that window when it does not have a valid window handle for embedding - i.e. via the libvlc_window_set_hwnd API call on Windows, which vlcj uses for its Embedded media player components. So, is the video I can see in the background of your picture actually appearing in a JFrame you created? Also, run the vlcj TestPlayer and see if the same thing happens or not.

Comment: I fixed the problem and asnwered the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video survace is shown in a JPanel in my applet. But before displaying i create a background task to download VLC dlls as zip and extract them to a temporary folder. When task is done execution of program jumps to main thread and video surface is added to JPanel. Then this. problem is occuring. I create a new task that runs on downloader task's completion. This new task do nothing and when it is done execution continues in main thread. This way this problem is gone.